# Example of persisting an inheritance relationship using ORM

Tags: inheritance, orm

I have some experience with OOP and RDBs, but very little exposure to web programming. I am trying to understand what **non-trivial** types of problems are solved by ORM. Of course, I am familiar with the need for **data** persistence, but I have never encountered a need for persisting **relationships between objects**, a situation which is indicated in many online articles about ORM.

I am not asking about the **process** of persisting a POJO to a database and restoring it later. Nor am I asking about why ORM **frameworks** are useful -- or a pain in the butt -- for doing so. I am particularly interested in how the need arises to persist and restore **relationships between objects**.

In various documentation, I have seen many examples of persisting POJOs to a database, but the examples have all been for only very simple objects that are essentially nothing more than records anyway: a constructor, some private fields, and getter/setter methods. The motivation for persisting such an "object-record" seems obvious and trivial.  This example:

[Hibernate ORM Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibern...m_overview.htm)

offers such an example, but goes on to discuss mismatch issues of granularity, inheritance, identity, associations, and navigation that are not motivated by the example.

If someone could offer a toy example of an instance where, say, the need arises to persist an inheritance relationship, I would be grateful. This might be blindingly obvious for anyone who has already encountered this situation but I have not and a great deal of searching and reading have not turned up any examples.

Comment: "*Where* the need arises to persist an inheritance relationship"? Well, it arises whenever you have a domain model with inheritance in it, and you need to persist the whole shebang. Are you really asking *how* to represent inheritance in SQL schemas? In that case, see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/160473/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-inheritance-with-orms

Comment: It was the need to persist the whole shebang that was eluding me. I wasn't thinking through the specifics of restoring a child class as an object.  Obviously, to instantiate a child you need to know that you must also instantiate the parent.  I was thinking about this entirely too abstractly.  Thanks for taking the time to reply.